# Problem with my function : updateChannel for discord js

Tags: javascript, discord

I would like you to ask for help with a function that I created that allows refreshing the channels that are in the list, but I have a problem, every 10 seconds the memory only goes up and never she empties herself. It's been over 5 hours that I'm looking for, even if I think it's a stupid thing, thank you for your help in advance (sorry for the translation, I'm not English)

My code :

```
updateChannel: async function(client, newList){
    let a = setInterval(async ()=> {
        for(let i = 0; i < newList.length; i++){
            const message = await this.replace$Var(client, newList[i][1])
            const channel = await client.channels.get(newList[i][0])
            channel.setName(message).catch(err => {
                console.log(`The channel with the id : ${newList[i][0]} was deleted, please restart the bot`)
                newList.splice(i,1)
                i-=1
            })
        }
        clearInterval(a)
        this.updateChannel(client, newList)
    }, 10000)
}
```

Comment: Why do you set interval then clear interval? rather than just using `setTimeout` ?

Comment: normally the manipulation of the clearInterval would remove the cache, but apparently it does not work

Comment: So try altering your code to use a `setTimeout` and see if you face the same issue.

Comment: I want to do the same as the setinterval but remove the cache each time because the ram is only going up, and I already try with the settimeout but it's the same

Comment: `setInterval` or `setTimeout` won't fix the recursion creating new stack frames and copies of variables every time. There's not even a reason to use recursion here, just have a setInterval that takes care of it without destroying itself and don't recurse

Answer (score 0):

Don't use setInterval this way. Use setTimeout. By calling setInterval, you create a UNIQUE timer every time the function is called. SetTimeout would create one timer that ends, and then creates a new timer.

try something like this:

```
updateChannel: async function(client, newList){
  for (let i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) {
    const message = await this.replace$Var(client, newList[i][1])
    const channel = await client.channels.get(newList[i][0])
    channel.setName(message).catch(err => {
      console.log(`The channel with the id : ${newList[i][0]} was deleted, please restart the bot`)
      newList.splice(i, 1)
      i -= 1
    })
  }
  setTimeout(this.updateChannel , 100000, client, newList);
}
```

Comment: it's worse this way

Comment: What do you mean with worse?

Comment: 100mo in 20 seconds :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the way you're using this that you don't need recursion at all, and having unchecked infinite recursion like this will only cause memory issues as node creates more and more stack frames and captures variables.

Try writing it without recursion:

```
updateChannel: function(client, newList) {
    return setInterval(async ()=> {
        for(let i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) {
            const message = await this.replace$Var(client, newList[i][1])
            const channel = await client.channels.get(newList[i][0])
            channel.setName(message).catch(err => {
                console.log(`The channel with the id : ${newList[i][0]} was deleted, please restart the bot`)
                newList.splice(i,1)
                i-=1
            })
        }
    }, 10000)
}
```

I return the return value of `setInterval` so that the caller can store it and clear it later if needed.

Comment: No it's the same like that :/ my memory growUp again :/

Comment: Can you share the code that calls this function as well? Setting a single interval isn't likely to cause that much memory leakage. Please also confirm that removing/not calling this function solves the memory problem.

Comment: It could even be `this.replace$Var()`. We don't really have enough information as-is, as this code alone does not constitute a memory leak.